# i3s Scene Layer Transparency adjustment on Deck.gl

Tags: esri, deck.gl

I want to adjust the display transparency of an ESRI i3s scene layer (https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/6j1KwZfY2fZrfNMR/arcgis/rest/services/Buildings_L1/SceneServer) on deck.gl Currently, we can only modify the color by `_getMeshColor` [deck.gl function](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/geo-layers/tile-3d-layer#callbacks). May I know any approach to adjust the layer transparency?